# Consolidate tuple and render as histogram using Python

Tags: python, histogram, data-processing

At the moment I have a list of tuples sorted by the second element in each tuple:

```
[('0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63',
  '121000'),
 ('0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26',
  '121000'),
 ('0x8b0fe2b7727664a14406e7377732caed94315b026b37577e2d9d258253067553',
  '21000'),
 ('0x0abe75e40a954d4d355e25e4498f3580e7d029769897d4187c323080a0be0fdd',
  '21000'),
 ('0x8adfe7fc3cf0eb34bb56c59fa3dc4fdd3ec3f3514c0100fef800f065219b7707',
  '40000'),
 ('0x244b29b60c696f4ab07c36342344fe6116890f8056b4abc9f734f7a197c93341',
  '50000'),
 ('0x22c2b6490900b21d67ca56066e127fa57c0af973b5d166ca1a4bf52fcb6cf81c',
  '90000'),
 ('0x8570106b0385caf729a17593326db1afe0d75e3f8c6daef25cd4a0499a873a6f',
  '90000')]
```

What I'd like to do is consolidate this set such that the second element in each tuple becomes the key, and the number of times it appears becomes the value, like this:

```
'90000':  2
'50000':  1
'40000':  1
'21000':  2
'121000': 2
```

Ultimately I'd like to render this as a histogram, but I'm not sure how to effect this consolidation operation and what data structure would be most suitable for subsequently generating a corresponding histogram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse it into a "flat list" of the second element of each tuple:

```
>>> my_list = [('0xf2b5b8fb173e371cbb427625b0339f6023f8b4ec3701b7a5c691fa9cef9daf63',
          '121000'),
         ('0xf8f2a397b0f7bb1ff212b6bcc57e4a56ce3e27eb9f5839fef3e193c0252fab26',
          '121000'),
         ('0x8b0fe2b7727664a14406e7377732caed94315b026b37577e2d9d258253067553',
          '21000'),
         ('0x0abe75e40a954d4d355e25e4498f3580e7d029769897d4187c323080a0be0fdd',
          '21000'),
         ('0x8adfe7fc3cf0eb34bb56c59fa3dc4fdd3ec3f3514c0100fef800f065219b7707',
          '40000'),
         ('0x244b29b60c696f4ab07c36342344fe6116890f8056b4abc9f734f7a197c93341',
          '50000'),
         ('0x22c2b6490900b21d67ca56066e127fa57c0af973b5d166ca1a4bf52fcb6cf81c',
          '90000'),
         ('0x8570106b0385caf729a17593326db1afe0d75e3f8c6daef25cd4a0499a873a6f',
          '90000')]
>>> flat_list = [x[1] for x in my_list]
```

Then you can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each element appearance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(flat_list)
Counter({'121000': 2, '21000': 2, '90000': 2, '40000': 1, '50000': 1})
```

**EDIT**

As you wanted a threshold, you can add a condition to the list comprehension:

`flat_list = [x[1] for x in my_list if int(x[1]) > 1000]`

**P.S**

`Counter` is a dict subclass so you should be able to do anything you want just like dict, but you can also cast it with `dict(counter_result)`

Comment: wow- thank you- this is an excellent answer! -while we're on the subject- do you know a good way to prune all the records with values lower than some threshold?

Comment: Yep, you can easily add a condition, check my edit.

Comment: hmm, I just tried it out, but it seems it didn't recognize the conditional threshold

Comment: It works for me, change the `1000` to your threshold.

Comment: Yep, I tried to set it high and got only 2 results. Make sure you don't confuse  with int/strings and the threshold is high enought.